# How to format the table like this

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, microsoft-excel-365

I have the following [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3SpE.png) and past it for test case in CSV format too:

```
;;Prediction;;;;Real Result
;;Shares;;Likes;;Shares;Likes;Notes
;;min;max;min;max
;;108;2220;1711;17086;206;2800;The Range is too Large
;;175;2220;3486;17086;237;4100;The Range is too Large
;;89;2220;1512;17086;158;2400;The Range is too Large
;;108;175;1711;3486;436;6300
;;144;2220;1803;17086;144;1800
;;144;2259;1803;17562;130;1600
```

I want to color the G column based on those rules:
if the value is between the values in C and D columns it should have a green background
if the value is smaller than the value in C or it is bigger then the value in D, it should have a red background. 
Please explain me how to do that. I understand I should do it with conditional formatting, but I don't find exactly the necessary options.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is what you need to do step-by-step:

1. Select the table or range where you want to change the background color of cells e.g =$G$4:$G$9.
2. Navigate to the Home tab, Styles group, and choose Conditional Formatting > New Rule….
3. In the New Formatting Rule dialog box, select "Use a formula to determine which tells to format" under "Select a Rule Type" box in the lower part of the dialog box.
4. In the lower part of the dialog box under "Format values where this formula is true", set the rule conditions. Please enter a formula  `=AND($G4>VALUE($C4);$G4<VALUE($D4))` for green backgrounf
5. Create a second formula `=OR($G4<VALUE($C4);$G4>VALUE($D4))` for red background

I added two screenshots below. You can use the Rules Manager for editing later.

[image]

[image]